# Alter service (ClientManager) based on configuration inside bundle extension class

Tags: symfony

I have a bundle named: "ApiBundle". In this bundle I have the class "ServiceManager", this class is responsible for retrieving a specific *Service* object. Those *Service* objects needs to be created based on some configuration, so after this piece of code in my bundle extension class:

```
$configuration = new Configuration();
$config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

$loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.yml');

// Create Service objects...
```

I create those *Service* objects right after I have processed the configuration, something like this:

```
foreach ($services as $name => $service) {
    $service = new Service();
    $service->setName($name);

    $manager = $container->get($this->getAlias() . '.service_manager');
    $manager->add($service);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, probably because the container isn't compiled yet. So I tried to add those *Service* objects the following way:

```
$manager = $container->getDefinition($this->getAlias() . '.service_manager');
$manager->addMethodCall('add', array($service));
```

But again, this throws the following exception: `RuntimeException: Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.`

I can't seem to get a grasp on how to use the service container correctly. Does someone knows how I can add those *Service* objects to the *ServiceManager* (which is a service) inside the bundle extension class?

This is how the configuration of the bundle looks like:

```
api_client:
    services:
        some_api:
            endpoint: http://api.yahoo.com
        some_other_api:
            endpoint: http://api.google.com
```

Every 'service' will be a seperate *Service* object.

I hope I explained it well enough, my apologies if my english is incorrect.

Steffen

**EDIT**

I think I may have solved the problem, I made a Compiler Pass to manipulate the container there with the following:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $services = $container->getParameter('mango_api.services');

    foreach ($services as $name => $service) {
        $clientManager = $container->getDefinition('mango_api.client_manager');

        $client = new Definition('Mango\Bundle\ApiBundle\Client\Client', array($name, 'client', 'secret'));
        $container->setDefinition('mango_api.client.' .$name, $client);

        $clientManager->addMethodCall('add', array($client));
    }
}
```

Is this appropriate?

Comment: Yep, compiler pass is exactly what you needed, move your `EDIT` part to answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have solved the problem, I made a Compiler Pass to manipulate the container there with the following:

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $services = $container->getParameter('mango_api.services');

    foreach ($services as $name => $service) {
        $clientManager = $container->getDefinition('mango_api.client_manager');

        $client = new Definition('Mango\Bundle\ApiBundle\Client\Client', array($name, 'client', 'secret'));
        $client->setPublic(false);

        $container->setDefinition('mango_api.client.' .$name, $client);

        $clientManager->addMethodCall('add', array($client));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To create services based on configuration you need to create [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass) and [enable](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) it.

> Compiler passes give you an opportunity to manipulate other service
>   definitions that have been registered with the service container.