# Inject a Symfony service specified in config.yml into a bundle's service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, bundle

I have a config.yml where I want to allow developer to pass the name of the cache service.

```
file_repository:
    cache_service: "cache"
```

Now I have the bundle *Configuration*

```
<?php

namespace Wolnosciowiec\FileRepositoryBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * @package Wolnosciowiec\FileRepositoryBundle\DependencyInjection
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('file_repository');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('cache_service')
                ->isRequired()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And I have the extension:

```
<?php

namespace Wolnosciowiec\FileRepositoryBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

/**
 * @package Wolnosciowiec\FileRepositoryBundle\DependencyInjection
 */
class FileRepositoryExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * Load configuration definition from "Configuration.php"
     *
     * @param array $configs
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        // inject the cache service into the Comrade Reader
        $comrade = $container->getDefinition('wolnosciowiec.comrade.reader');
        $comrade->addMethodCall('setCache', $container->get($config['cache_service']));
    }
}
```

In last lines I have injection of a service (specified in the configuration) into a internal service of the bundle in a setCache() method.

But I'm getting this:

ServiceNotFoundException in ContainerBuilder.php line 816:
You have requested a non-existent service "cache".

Even if in config/services.yml I have defined:

```
services:
    cache:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache
```

And the file loads FIRST.

How I could inject the switchable/configurable service properly to the bundle's service?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While building the container, you can't get services from the container, only service definitions. What you want to do is:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

...
$comrade->addMethodCall('setCache', new Reference($config['cache_service']));
...
```

Such a reference will be resolved when the service is being instantiated, and instantiate the cache if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a Compiler Pass instead of an Extension. The Extension only loads the configuration, it doesn't process it into the Container Builder yet. It's the Compiler Passes' responsibility to manipulate service definitions, as described [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

First, in the extension, you must read the configuration entry and store it as a parameter in the container:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    // ...
    $container->setParameter('cache_service', $config['cache_service']);
}
```

Then, create your Compiler Pass and configure your service there. Since the services are not instantiated yet, you must use a reference to your service instead. Retrieve the name of the service from the container:

```
// Wolnosciowiec\DependencyInjection\CacheCompilerPass:

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class CacheCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // get the service name from the container
        $id = $container->getParameter('cache_service');
        // inject the cache service into the Comrade Reader
        $comrade = $container->getDefinition('wolnosciowiec.comrade.reader');
        $comrade->addMethodCall('setCache', new Reference($id)));
    }
}
```

Then, register your Compiler Pass in your Bundle class:

```
// Wolnosciowiec\FileRepositoryBundle:

public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $container->addCompilerPass(new CacheCompilerPass());
}
```

Comment: [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException]             
  Unable to dump a service container if a parameter is an object or a resource.

This also wont work :)

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you have to use a reference in the compiler pass instead of the actual service. Edited my answer. Now you will be able to use the service name instead of its class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a clue in here:
[Alter service (ClientManager) based on configuration inside bundle extension class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305179/alter-service-clientmanager-based-on-configuration-inside-bundle-extension-cla)

So, finally with one compromise the compiler pass looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Wolnosciowiec\FileRepositoryBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class CacheCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $config = $container->getExtensionConfig('file_repository');

        // inject the cache service into the Comrade Reader
        $comrade = $container->getDefinition('wolnosciowiec.comrade.reader');

        $comrade->addMethodCall('setUrl',        [$config[0]['url']]);
        $comrade->addMethodCall('setToken',      [$config[0]['token']]);

        // serializer
        $serializer = new Definition(Serializer::class, []);
        $serializer->setPublic(false);
        $container->setDefinition('wolnosciowiec.file_repository.serializer', $serializer);
        $comrade->addMethodCall('setSerializer', array($serializer));

        // cache
        $cache = new Definition($config[0]['cache_class'], []);
        $cache->setPublic(false);
        $container->setDefinition('wolnosciowiec.file_repository.cache', $cache);
        $comrade->addMethodCall('setCache', array($cache));
    }
}
```

By compromise I mean I had to pass a class name from config.yml instead of a service name. It works nice, but it would be nicer if I would be able to pass the service id also.